# Вызвать контекстное меню по правому клику на вкладку в QTabWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, интерфейс

У меня есть `QTabWidget`, в котором у меня `QTableWidget`'ы. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне открыть контекстное меню по нажатию на вкладку "Процессы"? Я знаю как нарисовать меню, проблема в определение куда я кликнул. Клик можно отловить по `customContextMenuRequested`, но как понять, что я кликнул именно на вкладку "Процессы"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте обработку сигнала `tabBarClicked` для `QTabWidget`. Сигналом передается порядковый номер (`index`) вкладки, на которую нажали.

Если необходимо получить название вкладки, то: `tabwidget.tabText(index)`

**UPD**

Как можно сделать, чтобы события происходили только по нажатию на правую кнопку мыши. Для этого используется фильтр событий для виджета `QTabBar`.

**widget.h**

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H
#include <QWidget>
#include <QTabWidget>

#include "filter.h"
class Filter;

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QTabWidget *tabwdg;
    bool allowMenuShow = false; // этим флагом устанавливается разрешение для появления меню или другого события

    Filter *filter;

public slots:
    void setAllowMenuShow(bool);
    void click(int); // слот для обработки нажатия
public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();
    bool getAllowMenuShow();
};
#endif // WIDGET_H
```

**filter.h**

```
#ifndef FILTER_H
#define FILTER_H

#include <QWidget>
#include "widget.h"

class Widget;

class Filter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    Widget *root;
protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event);
public:
    Filter(QWidget *wdg, Widget *root);
    ~Filter();
};

#endif // FILTER_H
```

**widget.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "filter.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QTabBar>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QHBoxLayout>


Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    tabwdg = new QTabWidget();
    tabwdg->setParent(this);

    QTabBar *bar = tabwdg->tabBar();
    filter = new Filter(bar, this);
    bar->installEventFilter(filter); // установка фильтра обработки событий

    tabwdg->addTab(new QWidget(), "first");
    tabwdg->addTab(new QWidget(), "second");

    QHBoxLayout *box = new QHBoxLayout();
    box->addWidget(tabwdg);
    setLayout(box);

    connect(tabwdg, SIGNAL(tabBarClicked(int)), this, SLOT(click(int)));

}

void Widget::click(int i)
{
    if (getAllowMenuShow()) 
        qDebug() << tabwdg->tabText(i); // заменить на показ меню или другое
}
void Widget::setAllowMenuShow(bool f)
{
    allowMenuShow = f;
}
bool Widget::getAllowMenuShow()
{
    return allowMenuShow;
}

Widget::~Widget() {}


Filter::Filter(QWidget *wdg, Widget *root)
    : QObject(wdg), root(root) {}

bool Filter::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress) {
        QMouseEvent *mevent = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event);

        if (mevent->button() == Qt::RightButton) {
            root->setAllowMenuShow(true);
        } else {
            root->setAllowMenuShow(false);
        }
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(watched, event); // обработка события по-умолчанию
}

Filter::~Filter() {}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.resize(300, 300);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Мне нужно реагировать только на клик правой кнопкой мыши, как можно фильтр сделать? Если создавать свой класс и переписывать mousePressEvent, то как узнать, на какую вкладку нажали?

Comment: У `QMouseEvent` есть метод `button` - 1 - left, 2 - right. Только лучше установить `eventFilter` для `QTabBar`, так как в `mousePressEvent` вы не будете получать номер вкладки.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте принадлежность курсора вкладке. Для

```
void MainWindow::on_tabWidget_customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &pos)
{
    if (ui->tabWidget->tabBar()->tabRect(2).contains(pos))
```